# Main thread exception

Tags: java, selenium, winium

I am automating desktop application using Winium. I am trying to launch winium desktop server using script. Whenever I try to do that I am getting below exception
**Note:** If I launch the desktop server manually I am not getting any errors

```
exception in thread main java.lang.nosuchmethoderror com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.create(Ljava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;)LCom/google/common/util/concurrent/SimpleTimeLimiter;
at org.openqa.Selenium.net.urlchecker.<init>(Urlchecker.java:62)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:187)
at org.openqa.Selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:83)
```

Code I used to launch my application is below

```
String applicationpath="//my app path";
String winiumDriverPath="//path to my winium driver";
DesktopOptions options = new DesktopOptions();
options.setApplicationPath(//applicationpath);
WiniumDriverService service = new WiniumDriverService.Builder().usingDriverExecutable(new
File(winiumDriverPath)).usingPort(9999).withVerbose(true).withSilent(false).buildDesktopService();
service.start(); // getting error here    
driver = new WiniumDriver(service, options);
```

Kindly suggest me some ways to overcome this error.

Comment: See if you find something relevant here : https://github.com/citrusframework/citrus/issues/294

Answer (score 0):

Actually this should be a comment, but I don't  have the reputation :)

NoSuchMethodError may be caused if you have multiple versions of an API in your dependency. Mostly because one of your dependencies imports it a second time. It might be worth a try to check your dependencies.